# How do you mark a translator's note?

Tags: translation

Inside a piece of text, I have a word in another language. I'd like to keep it that way, and add a translator's note with the translation to English. What is the common practice of doing that?

I'd prefer to do it inline. I'm thinking of something like this:

> *word* (TN: *translation of word*)

But I haven't seen this notation used anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [Google Books search](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22translator%27s+note%22+%22tn%22&btnG=Search+Books) seems to confirm that the usual abbreviation for “translator's note” is indeed *TN*. The first time you use it, you may do so in full, so that the abbreviation is clear later.

In your particular context, however, it might simply be possible to state the translation inside the parentheses. Using the German *Länder* as an example, it might give:

> Many *Länder* (“provinces”) have different regulations on the issue

which I think is quite clear. You may even omit the quotes, I think.

Answer (score 4):

> The word *woord* ("word") ...
>
> The word *Wort* (German for "word") ...
>
> The word *mot* (Eng. "word") ...

All three choices would be fine in most texts. It may depend on your audience how much explanation the translation requires, whether the language of origin should be mentioned, etc. If your audience is fairly educated, you might be better off without translations of common foreign words, as your readers will not doubt know *mot* and *Wort* and might feel patronised—though few would probably know Dutch *woord*, unless it is obvious from context.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen many people mark a translator's note with "t/n" in almost all the comics I've read. You could try that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using first time 'translator's note' in full will clear later its abbreviation as t/n.